# Using Temporary Layer/not loaded Layer in Field Calculator

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing, toolbox

I'm writing a processing script with the given tools from the toolbox.
Now I want to use the Field Calculator to add a column to an output layer of a tool.
The Field Calculator/column should contain a 1/0 if a feature of a layer 'touches' any other feature in the same layer. Since the layer is not yet loaded, while I start the Field Calculator, I can't get it to work.
Another option was to call another function after the algorithm returns all values, but I don't know exactly where to call that function from `def processAlgorithm(...)`.

I tried different approaches for the `'FORMULA'`-parameter with the right results but only in QGIS with the loaded layer and not from Python.

```
fieldcalc_touches = processing.run("native:fieldcalculator", {
            'INPUT':polygonize['OUTPUT'],
            'FIELD_NAME':'HasNeighbours',
            'FIELD_TYPE':1,
            'FIELD_LENGTH':10,
            'FIELD_PRECISION':0,
            'FORMULA':'overlay_touches(@Layer_Name)',
            'OUTPUT':out_fieldcalc_touches},
            is_child_algorithm=True,
            context=context,
            feedback=feedback)

current += 1
feedback.setProgress(int(current * total))
```

Comment: Note the `overlay_touches()` expects the layer you'll use to check the touches predicate (not the layer of the current feature). Instead of passing the `@layer_name` variable to the expression function, have you tried passing the layer id (you can get it from `my_other_layer.id()`)? For instance, it could be something like `overlay_touches('My_Other_Layer_8eabcbb0_b884_49d6_a071_20d50b9ae8f6')`.